# How to use Adam optimizer in code instead of L-BFGS-B for constrained optimization

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I was using old source code and was using Scipy's L-BFGS-B algorithm. I have inaccuracies with it, though.

I got the following instructions:
In general, if you're having issues with L-BFGS-B, you also might want to try projected Adam or some other similar algorithm. There is really nothing special about L-BFGS-B for solving that problem, it just was convenient at that time for me. You can start off from the optim.Adam code and after each step, clamp x to be within your bounds.

I was wondering how to change the following code to use ADAM instead of L-BFGS-B. I am unfamiliar with Scipy. Please help because I'm a beginner

```
def get_sharpness(data_loader, model, criterion, epsilon, manifolds=0):

  # extract current x0
  x0 = None
  for p in model.parameters():
    if x0 is None:
      x0 = p.data.view(-1)
    else:
      x0 = torch.cat((x0, p.data.view(-1)))
  x0 = x0.cpu().numpy()

  # get current f_x
  f_x0, _ = get_minus_cross_entropy(x0, data_loader, model, criterion)
  f_x0 = -f_x0
  logging.info('min loss f_x0 = {loss:.4f}'.format(loss=f_x0))

  # find the minimum
  if 0==manifolds:
    x_min = np.reshape(x0 - epsilon * (np.abs(x0) + 1), (x0.shape[0], 1))
    x_max = np.reshape(x0 + epsilon * (np.abs(x0) + 1), (x0.shape[0], 1))
    bounds = np.concatenate([x_min, x_max], 1)
    func = lambda x: get_minus_cross_entropy(x, data_loader, model, criterion, training=True)
    init_guess = x0
  else:
    warnings.warn("Small manifolds may not be able to explore the space.")
    assert(manifolds<=x0.shape[0])
    #transformer = rp.GaussianRandomProjection(n_components=manifolds)
    #transformer.fit(np.random.rand(manifolds, x0.shape[0]))
    #A_plus = transformer.components_
    #A = np.linalg.pinv(A_plus)
    A_plus = np.random.rand(manifolds, x0.shape[0])*2.-1.
    # normalize each column to unit length
    A_plus_norm = np.linalg.norm(A_plus, axis=1)
    A_plus = A_plus / np.reshape(A_plus_norm, (manifolds,1))
    A = np.linalg.pinv(A_plus)
    abs_bound = epsilon * (np.abs(np.dot(A_plus, x0))+1)
    abs_bound = np.reshape(abs_bound, (abs_bound.shape[0], 1))
    bounds = np.concatenate([-abs_bound, abs_bound], 1)
    def func(y):
      floss, fg = get_minus_cross_entropy(x0 + np.dot(A, y), data_loader, model, criterion, training=True)
      return floss, np.dot(np.transpose(A), fg)
    #func = lambda y: get_minus_cross_entropy(x0+np.dot(A, y), data_loader, model, criterion, training=True)
    init_guess = np.zeros(manifolds)

  #rand_selections = (np.random.rand(bounds.shape[0])+1e-6)*0.99
  #init_guess = np.multiply(1.-rand_selections, bounds[:,0])+np.multiply(rand_selections, bounds[:,1])

  minimum_x, f_x, d = sciopt.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, init_guess, maxiter=10, bounds=list(bounds), disp=1, iprint=101)
```

And get_minus_cross_entropy is defined as

```
def get_minus_cross_entropy(x, data_loader, model, criterion, training=False):
  if type(x).__module__ == np.__name__:
    x = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
    x = x.cuda()
  # switch to evaluate mode
  model.eval()

  # fill vector x of parameters to model
  x_start = 0
  for p in model.parameters():
    psize = p.data.size()
    peltnum = 1
    for s in psize:
      peltnum *= s
    x_part = x[x_start:x_start+peltnum]
    p.data = x_part.view(psize)
    x_start += peltnum

  result, grads = forward(data_loader, model, criterion, 0,
                 training=training, optimizer=None)
  #print ('get_minus_cross_entropy {}!'.format(-result['loss']))
  return (-result['loss'], None if grads is None else grads.cpu().numpy().astype(np.float64))
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: minimum_x, f_x, d = sciopt.fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, init_guess, maxiter=10, bounds=list(bounds), disp=1, iprint=101) uses L-BFGS-B algorithm, but it has an early termination in the line search. Thus it probably returns an inaccurate f_x value